# Permission level to edit My Regional Setting

Tags: 2010, permissions, regional-settings

I want to set a permission level for a group of users only to be able to change the My Regional Setting. I have made a custom permission level with the "Edit Personal User Information" check on. They still get an access denied. They have only access to some lists and limited to root. What should they have more for permissions?

Comment: Do you want to change the "Regional Settings" which comes under the Site Administration section on site settings page or My sites regional settings...??

Comment: "My Regional Setting". Like already said in my post...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out that you also need the "View Pages" Permission Level.

Answer (score 0):

See the question wasnt clear enough . Are you attempting to change regional settings on Web Application level or site collection level ?

Do you want to change regional settings for team sites or mysite ?

One thing is for sure , if you want to change regional settings in list/libraries that cannot be done because they follow Site collection level permissions for editing regional settings.

You need to be site collection administrator if you want to do that.

Let me know if any doubts !!

Comment: On site level, the My Regional Setting through My Settings of the users profile.

Comment: okay so you want to change regional setting for particular users right ?

Comment: If you want to edit on my site of a user , you need to go to the mysites page of user by clicking on the user name . In the edit details in the language and region you need to change the option for regional setting to always use my regional settings otherwise it will inherit from site collection.  For this you need to have permission on user profile service application to modify user profiles . Let me know if this is  not clear